# How to provide a list of hostname in `kubernetes.io/hostname` nodeSelector

Tags: kubernetes

I  need to provide a list of hostnames under `kubernetes.io/hostname` nodeSelector. I tried giving comma separated list but kubernetes throws some validation error when I do `kubectl apply -f <yaml file>`.

I also tried giving multiple hostnames by providing repeated sets of `kubernetes.io/hostname` , but kubernetes takes only the last value.
Could not find any valid example when I browsed.

Thanks

```
The DaemonSet "ssh-daemonset" is invalid: spec.template.spec.nodeSelector: Invalid value: "1z.t3.x52.y7,l0.1k7.1p0.2q0": a valid label must be an empty string or consist of alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'MyValue',  or 'my_value',  or '12345', regex used for validation is '(([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9_.]*)?[A-Za-z0-9])?')
```

Comment: You cannot. Labels are key-value pairs and the value -- as conveyed by the error message -- must be a single value (`alphanumeric characters, '-', '_' or '.'`). In Kubernetes, constraints are usually label values that refer to multiple resources rather than to more ephemeral resources such as specific nodes, specific pods etc. The example given in the documentation explains this well and constrains a Pod to any node that has a `disktype` of `ssd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To constrain DaemonSet pods to run on specific nodes only, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/#running-pods-on-only-some-nodes

Using the same label, label the nodes on which you want the DaemonSet pods to run (`kubectl label nodes <node-name> <label-key>=<label-value>`) and specify that label in `spec.template.spec.nodeSelector`.

Example:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector